# HTMLCollection memory leak in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, htmlcollection

**EDIT:** See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=707544 for relevant issue and information about the bug.

Not necessary to answer this question from now on but retain the question for reference.

---

Element.getElementsByTagName return HTMLCollection in Chrome.

It stops GC from collecting the Element which called by or referenced from.

Although nothing found in Detached DOM tree, Nodes count (and probably heap size) increased unexpectedly.

The following demonstrates the result of **clicking the button** in the page which the code is provided below and **forcing GC** **alternatively**. (Heap size are dropped after Major GC/DOM GC but not Nodes counts)

[image: Devtool Performance]

And memory information after the first allocation and forced GC.

[image: Devtool Memory]

In my opinion, those HTMLCollection maybe act as a cache/placeholder. Since its *parent* is a *temporary* element, unnecessary amount of copy of HTMLCollection remains even when those elements were removed and collected.

Observed on Chrome 57.0.2987.133 and Chromium 59.0.3058.0 in Win10.

Reproducible code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <input type="button" id="button">
    <script type="application/javascript">
        var button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var content = document.getElementById('content');
            for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
                var el = document.createElement("div");
                //var no_leak = el.querySelectorAll('SPAN'); // NodeList
                var leak = el.getElementsByTagName('SPAN'); // HTMLCollection
                content.appendChild(el);
                el.remove();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: GC is usually scheduled to run after the intensive calc is completed such as yours. I know the threshold was [adjusted in v51](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d2466040fdea5f25406f9c6ac07efab10c46548d), but maybe it had a relevant change [recently as well](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/master/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/heap/ThreadState.cpp). Consider submitting a bug report on https://crbug.com with an easy to repro test case html.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Allocation Timelines. See [Identify JS heap memory leaks with Allocation Timelines](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/#identify_js_heap_memory_leaks_with_allocation_timelines). It's a kind of realtime visualization of memory allocations.